# Artifactory server not avaiable on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am new to Jenkins and currently following a tutorial on how to intergrate it with artifactory. I have installed both my artifactory and Jenkins on the same server. I have also installed the artifactory plugin on the Jenkins server.

Unfortunately when i get to the section where i need to select the artifactory server, the drop down menu doesnt show the it. 
Below is a screenshot image of what i am referring to.

[Jenkins Server Build image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfRjc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first add an Artifactory server under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` - you'll find the `Artifactory` section there where you can add servers.

You should probably go over the plugin's [own documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin), it outlines the process in detail.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to see the configure system option and have now included the server in there.